# Getting null in when trying to get array in servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

I have a below set of code to get the table data in an array and pass the same to servlet through ajax call. But i am getting null. Please someone help me on what my mistake / how to get the required data since i am new to this servlet and web app. So far i tried with some examples given in SO. but i am clueless to get my expected data.

```
 var myTableArray = [];
        $("table#itemtable tr").each(function() { 
            var arrayOfThisRow = [];
            var tableData = $(this).find('td');
            if (tableData.length > 0) {
                tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
                myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
            }
        });

        alert(myTableArray); 
        $.ajax({
            url:"insertmasteritem",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data: {json:myTableArray},
            success:function(data){
                // codes....
           },
       });
```

Servlet code

```
String[] myJsonData = request.getParameterValues("json[]");
System.out.println("myJsonData.length"+myJsonData.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < myJsonData.length; i++) {

           String[] innerArray=myJsonData[i].split(",");  
           System.out.println(myJsonData[i]);
       }
```

Comment: S.i am receiving as below when i use buffer reader instead of getparameter. json%5B0%5D%5B%5D=1&json%5B0%5D%5B%5D=2604SSBT10X40

Comment: How does the json string (myTableArray) look like before it's sent to the servlet ?

Comment: @dsp_user: i have added that image. Please check

Comment: The text on that picture doesn't look like json at all. I'd expect something like { [  {"var1":"val1", "var2": "val2", "var3": "val3"}, {"var1":"val1", "var2": "val2", "var3": "val3"} ]} (e.g this json contains 2 objects, each of which has 3 fields/attributes/variables)

Comment: @dsp_user: Thats before stringify. can we pass without key also?

Comment: No, this is the kind of string you should send to the servlet. stringify is used for just that pupose (the keys (as well as the values), of course, should be present.

Comment: Oh okie. Thanks for notifying me. I am just getting table values in an array. For ex: [Apple, XYZ,10, OK,Orange,ABC,23,OK] in this way. Could you guide me to how to get those values in servlet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138716/discussion-between-dsp-user-and-kavi).

Comment: Sorry. I am not able access the link

Comment: Give me some time and I'll post some code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please post once you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Send your Json data like this

```
   $.ajax({
            url:"insertmasteritem",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data:myTableArray,
            success:function(data){
                // codes....
           },
   });
```

and In Servlet Class

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(request.getParameter("myTableArray"));
Iterator it = jsonObj.keys(); 

while(it.hasNext())
{
  String jsonKey = (String)it.next();
  String jsonValue = jsonObj.getString(jsonKey);
  System.out.println(jsonKey  + " --> " + jsonValue );
}
```

Comment: I think you are not sending json, first parse your array into json like this var json= JSON.stringify(myTableArray); and send this json data

Comment: @Dillip: I tried with the way of parse what you suggested. But i am getting null pointer exception even at a line JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(request.getParameter("myTableArray")); is that because of i am having null also in passing i/p?

Comment: Did u parse in JavaScript or java?

Comment: in JS var json= JSON.stringify(myTableArray);  and used  data: json,in ajax

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to send a properly formatted JSON object (as a string) to the servlet. Possibly the easiest way to do this is to create some javascript objects and fill an array with these objects. The array data should then be
converted to a JSON string (using JSON.stringify). I'm going to hardcode object values (but you will get them from your table)

Javascript code

```
function generateJson(){
  var myObjArr = [];
//you will typically have just one object (e.g. myObj, which you will fill  in your ajax table loop 
  //myObj.v1 = v1_val;
  //myObj.v2 = v2_val;
  ...
  //myObjArr[i] = myObj; //
  myObj1 = { "v1": "Orange", "v2": "ABC", "v3":10,"v4":"OK"  };
  myObj2 = { "v1": "Apple", "v2": "XYZ", "v3":25,"v4":"OK"  };

  myObjArr[0] = myObj1;
  myObjArr[1] = myObj2;

 var jsonObjStr = JSON.stringify(myObjArr);
 //you can now use jsonObjStr to send your data to the servlet
 // document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = jsonObjStr;//this is just added for testing purposes
 }
```

The generated JSON

```
[{"v1":"Orange","v2":"ABC","v3":10,"v4":"OK"},{"v1":"Apple","v2":"XYZ","v3":25,"v4":"OK"}]
```

As you can see, the json string starts with a [ (which denotes an array). You may have to change this to start with a { (and with a } ) depending on how your JSON parser works ({} denote an object).

For the servlet part, it depends on the actual JSON parser you're using. Try to use some of the suggestions provided by others. I can provide some code using Jackson though, but you will have to add the Jackson library to your classpath.

Answer (score -2):

why you are getting parameter value as JSON[]

```
String[] myJsonData = request.getParameterValues("json[]");
```